# Removed OneDrive, folders remain under "This PC" Explorer Pane

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I removed OneDrive, because I didn't use it, but then I notice, that the "Documents" folder in the "This PC" pane still has the OneDrive\Documents location. I want to have the local Documents folder to show up under "This PC". I already tried [This PC Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213) but it didn't even show the Documents folder. I also tried removing and restoring the registry keys for showing the Documents folder under "This PC", it worked, but the location stayed in the OneDrive folder. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the move option available in Documents folder properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
I had to modify the shell folders registry entries under HKEY_USERS. I found this out by serching the registry for the path of the Documents folder under "This PC".